# Erro na referência : Variável não foi definida

Tags: javascript

Porque apresenta erro na variável se em um fiddle ( -> http://jsfiddle.net/8xwqdk71/ <- ) não apresenta este erro?
Pode ser alguma outra coisa além de bibliotecas de Js? Pois todas já foram definidas

 (Código que ao clicar, gira a imagem)

```js
var value = 0
$("#image").rotate({
  bind: {
    click: function() {
      console.log(value);
      value += 90;
      $(this).rotate({
        animateTo: value
      })
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#image {
  margin: 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wilq32/jqueryrotate/master/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">
```

Comment: Perdão, referência, acusa este erro :
"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Faltou voce incluir o `jQuery` https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: Eu coloquei o 2.1.1, agora está dando erro na função rotate, precisará importar mais coisas certo?? (pois no site da JQueryRotate pediu para importar somente este e os que já tem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só inverter a ordem das chamadas dos scripts, e chamar o jQuery antes de todos.

Assim:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wilq32/jqueryrotate/master/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">
```

Comment: Ajustou :D
Porém agora está dando erro na função rotate e já importei as bibliotecas :(

Comment: Acho que é pq você está usando scripts que fazem praticamente a mesma coisa.

Eu testei aqui, funcionou somente usando o **jquery.min.js** e o **jQueryRotateCompressed.js**

Comment: Vou tentar novamente!! obg !!

Comment: Se precisar de referência, coloquei o código no **[GitHub](https://github.com/vicainelli/StackOverflow/blob/master/pt/240400/240400.html)**

Comment: Agora deu certo !!! valeu @Vinicius <3